# Windows connects, Ubuntu doesn't

Tags: networking, ip-address

I'm trying to connect to a school network that uses MAC filtering (and other restrictions?). I've been given an IP address specific to this machine, and it connects without problem in Windows 10. However, using the same IPv4 configuration (via networking gui) in Ubuntu 15.10 I get no connection. ifconfig shows I don't have an address.

Is there any way I can determine if the problem is my machine or the local servers? The support staff here is useless, just verified that I entered the static IP info correctly and then gave up.

About the machine: Windows and Linux are on separate drives. Someone else set up the computer and had networking functioning in both OSs.

Comment: Are you able to connect using Ubuntu to a different network (for example, at Starbucks?)

Comment: You mention that ifconfig shows no address, but also that you entered static IP info correctly somewhere. Which interface is in question?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this will help, but to set up a network, you open interfaces and fill in the details e.g

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.11
gateway 192.168.2.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.2.0
broadcast 192.168.2.255
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 ###Googles dns server
```